# Selenium C#: Is there a way to wait for loading overlay to hide before proceeding?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been creating different explicit waits after doing tasks like updating contact info, submitting forms, etc because every time I do this, a loading overlay will pop up for a few seconds. I just realized it's the same exact loading code on each page. Instead of waiting for results to show on the page or something else to appear, I just want to wait for this loading overlay to hide. Is it possible to write some reusable code to wait for this overlay to hide before proceeding?

The overlay code:

```html
<div id="progress" style="display: none;" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="divOverlay"></div>
    <div id="divLoading">
        <img id="loading" src="/loading.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When the loading display is present, the div attributes will become:

```html
<div id="progress" style="display: block;" role="status" aria-hidden="false">
  <div id="divOverlay"></div>
  <div id="divLoading">
    <img id="loading" src="/loading.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of .net supports `ExpectedConditions`, you can straight away use the below solution

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//div[@id='progress']")));
```

If it does not support then the below solution may work.

```
//returns as soon as element is not visible, or throws WebDriverTimeoutException
protected void WaitUntilElementNotVisible(By searchElementBy, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds))
                    .Until(drv => !IsElementVisible(searchElementBy));
}

private bool IsElementVisible(By searchElementBy)
{
    try
    {
        return _driver.FindElement(searchElementBy).Displayed;

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use it like this :

```
WaitUntilElementNotVisible(By.Id("progress"), 10);
```